# Embedded Font Issue on different Operating Systems

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, fonts, adobe

My Flex web page is using an embedded .otf font in the main css file:

```
@font-face {
 src:url("../assets/fonts/TradeGothic.otf");
 fontFamily: myTradeGothic;
}
```

I develop using Snow Leopard and the font appears fine in Safari, Firefox, and Chrome. When I view the page on a Windows machine, the font does not appear to be working in either IE or Firefox, but has defaulted to a different font which throws off all the spacing. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you should do when you're testing fonts is uninstall them from your system and make sure they render correctly.  Chances are they're only rendering correctly on your mac because the font is installed in your syste,.

That being said... As far as i know you cant load a regular font file at runtime and have it work.  You need to compile the font into a swf and load that swf at runtime into your app to access the font. That's also the way sifr ( http://www.mikeindustries.com/blog/sifr ) works.